# How can I be notified that a movie has been determined not to be a movie?

Tags: macos, avfoundation, avplayer

I'm writing a Mac app that plays MPEG-4 movies using AVPlayer.

My app supports both local movies and movies from the internet, via an “Open Location” dialog. In the latter case, when the user enters a URL and presses the OK button, my app opens the URL as a document.

Local files are easy—Launch Services will tell Finder, Dock, etc. not to light my app up for any local file that isn't a .mp4 or similar. If the user forces my app to open some random file (e.g., by holding down ⌘ when dragging it onto my app), that's their own fault.

Non-local (e.g., internet) URLs are the problem. If I supply a URL that *doesn't* lead to an MPEG-4, I need to show an alert and close the document.

Of course, I'm not downloading the URL myself; I just hand it to AVPlayer.

So I need a way to be notified by my AVPlayer that what I've given it is not a movie.

- I've tried observing the player's `status`. That gets set to `AVPlayerStatusReadyToPlay`.
- I've tried observing the player's `currentItem`'s `tracks`. At least on Lion, for an invalid movie, the item's `tracks` never changes. (This stands to reason—the only reason it would change would be tracks coming in, which is, by definition, impossible for a non-movie.)
- I can't just check `tracks` when `status` changes, because that may not be set yet (on Mavericks, `status` changes before `tracks`).

So, how can I be notified by my AVPlayer that it has conclusively determined that what the URL refers to is not anything it can play?

Answer (score 1):

It's absolutely not definitive, but in my experience, when the player's `status` becomes `AVPlayerStatusReadyToPlay`, you can inspect the `playable` property of `asset` of the player's `currentItem`. If `playable` is `YES`, you can assume the URL led to a viable MP4. If not, you can assume it did not.

```
- (void) observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString*)keyPath
                       ofObject:(id)object
                         change:(NSDictionary*)change
                        context:(void*)context
{
    if( [keyPath isEqualToString:@"status"] ) {
        if( self.player.status == AVPlayerStatusReadyToPlay && 
            self.player.currentItem.asset.playable ) {
            [self.playerView.player play];
        }
        else {
            // TODO: show an error dialog here.
            [self.window close];
        }
    }
}
```

I've code similar to the above in one of my apps, and it seems to work as expected in every case I've tried. I can whip up a test app with it if you like.

Comment: This works *most* of the time, but I just came across a movie for which it doesn't: the movie *is* playable (verified in an older build that didn't present this sheet), but the asset's `playable` is not true at that particular point in time.